# Proving this group is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,.)$ be a group where there exists an element $g \in G$ such that
for any $x \in G$ it is the case that $x^3 = gxg$.

I've been stumped on this one. All I have found is that $e = e^3 = geg = g^2$. Does anyone have advice on some starting points to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: It's redundant (and illogical) to write both "for any $x\in G$" *and* "for all $x\in G$" in the same claim.

Comment: Much more is true. You have $gx^3=xg=gx$, so $x^2=1$, so every element has order 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $a,b\in G$. Therefore, $(ab)^3=gabg=gag^2bg=a^3b^3$.

Comment: From this, I se that $baba=a^2b^2$. What’s the next step?

Comment: Using @almagest's comment, all the elements have order $2$.  So $baba=e\implies ba=a^{-1}b^{-1}=ab$.